# Do I need SiteLock on top of AWS Shield?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

My website is hosted on AWS and I am using the default AWS shield protection.

I am renewing my domain with a 3rd party provider, and the provider is asking me if I want to buy SiteLock for additional security... Do I need SiteLock if I am using AWS shield?

Comment: Probably not.  Depends if you want to be swayed by their advertising (that's what it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at the Sitelock website. It seems to be designed to scare people into using their services. Instead of providing information they make you enter contact details to get sent information. I'd not use them.

AWS Shield provides sufficient protection against many threads. AWS WAF and AWS Shield Advanced provide optional additional protection if you feel you need it.

CloudFlare is another great service provide that can sit in front of any website, AWS or otherwise, to provide additional protection. Make sure you configure your security groups to accept connections only from CloudFlare IPs and your home / work IPs. They have a useful free tier.